# Using httr::url_ok to validate URLs—stuck on certain URLs and timeout ignored

Tags: r, url, timeout

I'm trying to use `url_ok` with `pbsapply` to test a large number of URLs:

```
pbsapply(foo$URL, function(x) try(url_ok(x)))
```

but the program keeps getting stuck on certain bad URLs, like `url_ok("www.isdnet.net")`. This URL will return `403 Forbidden` in the browser, but makes R stuck. There are other bad URL situations, and I don't know how many bad URLs are in the big data set.

I tried to create a time out, making it stop if can't return anything after a few seconds, give it a `FALSE` and move on to the next URL.

I tried this but didn't work, still got stuck:

```
evalWithTimeout(url_ok("www.isdnet.net"), timeout=1.08, onTimeout="warning");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `HEAD` requests (which is what `url_ok` uses) do not work on all web servers and can send you into a timeout death-spiral *or* give you inaccurate results (amongst other issues). The only way to avoid this is to use a `GET` request which will result in downloading more payload. But, then you have to probably worry about malformed URLs (I've rarely come across a large, clean URL dataset) which will throw actual R errors. You're best bet is to write a more robust "URL OK" routine (UPDATED to add `timeout`):

```
library(httr)
library(pbapply)

# this is a dangerous setting for normal operations
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer=0L, ssl_verifyhost=0L), override=TRUE)

url_ok_via_get <- function(...) {

  ret <- FALSE

  tryCatch( {
x <- GET(..., timeout(5), user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36"))
    ret <- identical(status_code(x), 200L)
  }, error=function(e) {
    ret <- FALSE
  }, finally=return(ret))

}

url_ok_via_get("aladslsdf")
## [1] FALSE

url_ok_via_get("http://www.isdnet.net")
## [1] FALSE

url_ok_via_get("http://dds.ec/guaranteed_to_return_404")
## [1] FALSE

url_ok_via_get("http://rud.is/")
## [1] TRUE

url_ok_via_get("http://www.gn.dk")
## [1] FALSE

pbsapply(c("aladslsdf", "http://www.isdnet.net",
           "http://dds.ec/guaranteed_to_return_404", "http://rud.is/",
           "http://www.gn.dk"), url_ok_via_get)

##                              aladslsdf 
##                                  FALSE 
##                  http://www.isdnet.net 
##                                  FALSE 
## http://dds.ec/guaranteed_to_return_404 
##                                  FALSE 
##                         http://rud.is/ 
##                                   TRUE 
##                       http://www.gn.dk 
##                                  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this more robust version of URL_OK! I checked the bad URLs i found so far, and most of them work very well. There are a few valid URLs that url_ok sees as invalid, and this url_ok_via_get can identify them correctly. There is just this one URL: www.gn.dk. It keeps the browser stuck in searching and even makes url_ok_via_get get stuck. I'm not sure if you encounter this kind of situation before. Thanks again!

Comment: Huh. That one even causes Chrome to hang. I modified the function to add a 5s timeout (which should be plenty and can probably be adjusted town to below 1s if desired)

Comment: I ran into URLs like "www.merck.com". When entered into the browser, it will redirect me to "http://www.merck.com/index.html", and therefore i can open merck.com in the browser. However, when using the function or url_ok: url_ok_via_get("www.merck.com"),  it will return False. I tried to change the "200L" status code into other http status code, like 3xx, but still returned False, didnt work. Is there a way to modify the function and make it recognize merck.com as TRUE? Thank you!!

Comment: Merck is doing `User-Agent` filtering. While it's considered _really_ bad practice to use a normal browser user agent as the string in a crawler, I've modified the code to do so. Just be aware that is considered to be at the very least "rude". Sites that reject non-"real"-browser user agents are doing so for many reasons, so scaper-beware.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @hrbrmstr! Adding user agent worked for almost all the URL issues. There is this one last problem i can't solve: these URLs, "www.lacie.com",  "http://www.puratos.com" and "www.50Hertz.com", if i check their http_status, they are "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates", 500,"Failure when receiving data from the peer". However, they can all be opened in the browsers. Does this have anything to do with "add_headers". Can the function identify them as TRUE? Thank you!!

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258617/extract-information-from-json-file-by-making-get-requests-in-r/31258948#31258948